# Convert Json object to Json array of key-value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

What will be the best way to convert json object like

```
{"id" : 1, "name": "John"}
```

to json array

```
[{"id" : 1},{"name": "John"}]
```

using javascript.

Update:
I want to do it because in Sequelize I have to pass filters as Json array with operator "or" while i have that in Json.

Comment: Share your try please ? I can be easily done by for loop.

Comment: Converting JSON object to what. Whats your input, how should your output look like. What's your maingoal you want to achieve and whats not working?

Comment: do you need a special order of the items in the array?

Comment: I guess you don't understand that result you want to get doesn't make sense because it's irregular. You can do it maybe you need it indeed.

Comment: `Object.entries({"id" : 1, "name": "John"}).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))`

Comment: @NinaScholz No order is not important.

Comment: @everyone Have updated the question with my use case.

Comment: @dfsq It will remove quotes from keys and adding quote to integer value.

Comment: @Arpit Of course it will not. I guess the way you check it make you think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```js
let obj = {"id" : 1, "name": "John"};

let result = Object.keys(obj).map(e => {
    let ret = {};
    ret[e] = obj[e];
    return ret;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could map single key/value pairs.

```js
var object = { id: 1, name: "John" },
    result = Object.keys(object).map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John"
};
var arr = [];
for (var o in obj) {
  var _obj = {};
  _obj[o] = obj[o];
  arr.push(_obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of for loop

```js
var arr =  {"id" : 1, "name": "John"};
var newArr = [];
for(var i in arr){
  var obj={};
  obj[i] = arr[i];
  newArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work out.

```js
let object = {"id" : 1, "name": "John"};
let jsonArr = [];

let objectKeys = Object.keys(object)
for(i=0;i<objectKeys.length; i++) {
  jsonArr[i] = {};
  jsonArr[i][objectKeys[i]] = object[objectKeys[i]];  
}

console.log(jsonArr)
```